# error: ‘std::sin(x)’ cannot be used as a function

Tags: c++

Unable to compile C++ program in ubuntu.

```
float x;
x=(m*Ts1)-(n*Ts);
new_samples[m]=(original_samples[n*Ts]*(sin(x))(2*pi*B))/(2*pi*B*(x));
```

I want to use `sin` function in C++. I have included `cmath`. Still it is giving error:

> error: ‘std::sin(x)’ cannot be used as a function.

Comment: There's apparently a bug in the code which you're not showing. I suggest you fix it, then the compiler error will go away. (Or you can show the code and we can help you find the bug)

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) please

Comment: Here are the lines I am trying to debug

float x;
x=(m*Ts1)-(n*Ts);
new_samples[m]=(original_samples[n*Ts]*(sin(x))(2*pi*B))/(2*pi*B*(x));

I have declared x as float since the argument of sin should be float or double. All other variables are int

Comment: Well, that's by far not the smallest bit of code. If you had tried to simplify that, you'd have found the problem. Try to write in C++ `y = sin(2*π/8)` - you should know the result.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
(sin(x))(2*pi*B)
```

C++ does not have implicit multiplication like you might be accustomed to in math -- `(a)(b)` tries to call `a` as a function, not multiply `a` and `b`, and in this case, `a` is `sin(x)`.  The return value of `sin(x)` is a `double`, and a `double` is not a callable function.

You really wanted to write this:

```
(sin(x)) * (2*pi*B)
```

Comment: I'm glad someone took the time to answer this question rather than down vote + vote to close. Very nearly ended up with another disappointed newcomer due to overzealous voters :-/

Comment: @davbryn: Before any code was posted, it was unanswerable and was on its way in that direction; but after the code was posted, I removed my downvote and was able to answer it.

Comment: @Adam Rosenfield - Where does the "std::" in the error message come from? Using namespace std?

Comment: @laune: The compiler is adding it.  The function `sin()` is in the `std` namespace, so even if the code is written without the `std::` prefix by virtue of a `using namespace std;` or `using std::sin;` statement, the compiler knows to add the prefix in the error message so that the message is more helpful.

Comment: Sorry, doesn't make sense. Why multiply by `(2*pi*B)` if the next expression is dividing by `(2*pi*B*x)` ?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that `(sin(x)) * (2*pi*B))/(2*pi*B*(x))` is just `sin(x)/x;`, I strongly suspect that you wanted to write either `sin(2*pi*B) / (2*pi*B*(x));` or `sin(2*pi*B*x) / (2*pi*B*(x));`. (i.e. `sinc(2*pi*B*x)`, but that's not C++) .

We're guessing a bit, and so is the compiler. What you wrote just doesn't make a lot of sense.